# Codeigniter query create federated table

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to create a table with this function in Codeigniter

```
public function createTable($connectionString) {
    $createString = "CREATE TABLE {$this->getTabela()} (
        `data` datetime NOT NULL,
        `idempregado` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
        `nif` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
        `idsociedade` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        `tipo` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`data`),
        KEY `fk_assiduidade_user1` (`idempregado`,`nif`,`idsociedade`),
        CONSTRAINT `fk_assiduidade_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`idempregado`, `nif`, `idsociedade`) REFERENCES `user` (`idempregado`, `nif`, `idsociedade`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        )
        ENGINE=FEDERATED
        DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
        CONNECTION='$connectionString'";
    var_dump($createString);
    var_dump($this->getDbConnect()->conn_id);
    var_dump($this->getDbConnect()->query($createString));
}
```

But the query is always returning False. 
As you guys can see i already made 3 var_dumps to check if its all OK.
Ca you guys help me get to the point where this don't execute the query?

Regards,
Elkas

Comment: Have you tried checking for MySQL errors?  Checked logs?

Comment: Have you even looked at CI's db [***Forge class***](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem.

After talking with technicians at the Data center (because i dont have access to any logs) i found that they have the FEDERATED engine disabled.

Problem Solved.

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: you should still look at their [DB Forge](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html), it's alot easier and "safer" than doing it manually

Comment: Its ok mate. I've already read it before I posted here. But since my destination servers have static IP I don't need the federated table. Its a solution when I don't have know the "way" from the top to the bottom, but since I know it I can make the connections in the main server.